# Find item in dictionary where key is "Like" string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm getting a dictionary where I'm looking for items where the keys are "key_XXX_string". The XXX can vary. In TSQL I'd simply do

```
 select * from dictionary where key like 'key_%_string'
```

Is there a way to do it in Python?

Comment: There's no special way to do it, just run a O(n) loop over all the keys and compare them to your pattern (e.g. rewriting it to use regex).

Comment: post your input dictionary, does it have any other keys except "key_XXX_string" format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python , dictionaries is a mapping of key and value pairs

You need to iterate over items in your dictionary and check if your key matches the given pattern 'key_xxx_string'
You need **re** library to check for regular expression

So here is a simple code snippet serving what you can do in python 3.6 to print keys with their values that matches given regex 'key_xxx_string'

```
import re

for key, value in my_dict.items():
    if re.match('key_(.*)_string', key):
        print (key, value)
```

1) Here first line , is just import re library for regular expression matching

> import re

2) The second line is iterating over the items  in your dictionary

> for key, value in my_dict.items():

3) The third line is matching each key against the regex pattern 'key_xxx_string'

> if re.match('key_(.*)_string', key):

4) The fourth line is actually just printing the items in dictionary if the key matches

> print (key, value)

Answer (score 3):

As others have stated, dicts are made for quick hashed lookups, this said you will need to look at each key to find the value(s) you want.

This however *(atop [@Arushix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56616718/225020)'s answer)* can be done using a comprehension as well:

```
import re

[v for k, v in my_dict.items() if re.match('key_.*_string', k)]
```

You can even make your own class to do this for you:

```
class FuzzyDict(dict):

    def fetch(self, pattern):
        p = re.compile(pattern)
        return [v for k, v in self.items() if p.match(k)] or None

    def fetch_one(self, pattern):
        p = re.compile(pattern)
        for k, v in self.items():
            if p.match(k):
                return v
```

Then it's as simple as:

```
d.fetch("my_.*_string")
```

An example of usage would be:

```
data = FuzzyDict({'key_1_string':1, "key_2_string":2, "invalid": 3})

data.fetch("key_.*_string")
#[1,2]
data.fetch_one("key_.*_string")
#1
data.fetch("some text")
#None
```

This will default to `None` if nothing is found